# NoReverseMatch at /password_reset_complete/ 'users' is not a registered namespace

Tags: python, django

base urls.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from users import views as user_views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('register/', user_views.register , name='register'),
    path('login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='users/login.html'), name='login'),
    path('logout/', auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(template_name='users/logged_out.html'), name='logout'),
    path('password_reset/',
         auth_views.PasswordResetView.as_view(template_name='users/password_reset.html'),
         name='password_reset'),
    path('password_reset/done/',
         auth_views.PasswordResetDoneView.as_view(template_name='users/password_reset_done.html'),
         name='password_reset_done'),
    path('password_reset_confirm/<uidb64>/<token>/',
         auth_views.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(template_name='users/password_reset_confirm.html'),
         name='password_reset_confirm'),
    path('password_reset_complete/',
         auth_views.PasswordResetCompleteView.as_view(template_name='users/password_reset_complete.html'),
         name='password_reset_complete'),
    path('', include('learning_logs.urls')),
]
```

password_reset_confirm.html:

```
{% extends "learning_logs/base.html" %}
{% load bootstrap4 %}

{% block page_header %}
    <h2>Reset your password.</h2>
{% endblock page_header %}

{% block content %}
    <form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {%  bootstrap_form form %}
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
  </form>

{% endblock content %}
```

password_reset_complete.html:

```
{% extends "learning_logs/base.html" %}

{% block content %}
    <p>Password changed </p>
    <a href="{% url 'login' %}">Sign in</a>
{% endblock content %}
```

I've tried to find the reference to namespace 'users' which the error is referring to. But I have no idea where is the source. I get this error whenever I fill in password_reset_confirm fields for resetting the password. Any ideas?

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Shebeli\desktop\jango\ll_env\lib\site-packages\django\urls\base.py", line 72, in reverse
    extra, resolver = resolver.namespace_dict[ns]
KeyError: 'users'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Shebeli\desktop\jango\ll_env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\Shebeli\desktop\jango\ll_env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Users\Shebeli\desktop\jango\ll_env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Shebeli\desktop\jango\ll_env\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 71, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Shebeli\desktop\jango\ll_env\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 97, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Shebeli\desktop\jango\ll_env\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 158, in get
    context = self.get_context_data(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Shebeli\desktop\jango\ll_env\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\views.py", line 326, in get_context_data
    context['login_url'] = resolve_url(settings.LOGIN_URL)
  File "C:\Users\Shebeli\desktop\jango\ll_env\lib\site-packages\django\shortcuts.py", line 131, in resolve_url
    return reverse(to, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Shebeli\desktop\jango\ll_env\lib\site-packages\django\urls\base.py", line 83, in reverse
    raise NoReverseMatch("%s is not a registered namespace" % key)
django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: 'users' is not a registered namespace
```

Comment: @ Shervin Saeedi  I think the problem lies in the ```urls``` where you address templates ```template_name='users/password_reset_complete.html'``` , check if ```users``` (the folder and its contents) accessible.

Comment: @iliya if it is as you say, then the path `urls` before `template_name='users/password_reset_complete.html'` could also have given the same error?(I'm not sure). How can I see if `users` is accessible or not?

Comment: @ Shervin Saeedi  update your question and add hierarchy of your folders up to that folder ```users```.

Comment: @ Shervin Saeedi  those ```views``` configured to look for templates inside a folder named ```registration```. I didn't change the path and everything works fine. Just put all the templates inside a path like this ```app-name/templates/registration/``` and check again.

Comment: What is the `DIRS` list inside `settings.TEMPLATES` object? And does this `users` directory location is inside one of those `DIRS`?

Comment: @iliya I created another app named  `test123` and moved all the templates to `test123/templates/registration` but I get the same error `test123' is not a registered namespace`

Comment: @ Shervin Saeedi ok now remove ```template_name``` from your ```urls```.

Comment: @YasserMohsen the `DIRS` inside `settings.TEMPLATES` is the default value `BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))` and I haven't made any `DIRS` or change the base dir.

Comment: @iliya I've deleted the old one and assigned the `urls` to the new templates in `test123` but it still gives the same error

Comment: @ Shervin Saeedi  don't assign anything just remove that part something like this ```path('password_reset_confirm/<uidb64>/<token>/',
         auth_views.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(),
         name='password_reset_confirm')```.

Answer (score 0):

This solution generally may help here! It is better to define the templates directories `DIRS` list in `settings.TEMPLATES`

One of the common approaches is to have one inside each app with the below hierarchy:

```
testproject/
    testproject/
        settings.py
        urls.py
        ....
    users/
        models.py
        views.py
        ....
        templates/
            users/
                password_reset.html
                ....
    manage.py
    ....
```

Then, mention the templates DIRs explicitly at `settings.py`:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            'users/templates'
        ],
        ....
    }
]
```

This will avoid Django confusion. Now, you can add template_name as you mentioned above like: `template_name='users/password_reset.html'`

Answer (score 0):

in `settings.py` I had:
`LOGIN_URL = 'users:login` which should have been `LOGIN_URL = 'login'`